# Stop animation if page is already at destination

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently using a bit of javascript to move the user down to the location of the information they click on in a side navigation menu. However the problem being if they click on one item and then another item when they go to scroll away the animation is still trying to complete. Is there a way to prevent the js from running if already at the top of the scroll top destination. I have a `.stop()` in already to stop the original animation on click. Or possibly cancel animation on scroll away?

```
$('#zoomTo li a').on('click', function(e) {
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop : $('#scrollDest').offset().top - 20
    }, 1000);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: jquery holds a que for animations. There is also `finish()`. There are some nice examples to play with on the jquery site: http://api.jquery.com/finish/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the jquery site use:

```
.clearQueue().finish();
```

http://api.jquery.com/finish/

Comment: Was just coming around to that in the docs. I ended up using this so on any event the animation was cancelled. `$("html, body").on("scroll mousedown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup", function(){
       $('html, body').clearQueue().finish();
   });`. Thanks for the help

Comment: It is rewarding to check the docs first, but sometimes one just needs to know where to seek.